# rails postgres read array out of db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a postgres db with each row representing an "index" (just a name not the keyword). For each market, there is an attribute "stats" thats a two dimensional array of numbers that I put into the db from an external source.

```
 create_table "indices", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name",                     null: false
    t.float   "returns",     default: [],              array: true
    t.float   "navs",        default: [],              array: true
    t.float   "stats",       default: [],              array: true
    t.string  "updated_at"
    t.string  "created_at"
    t.integer "idx_type_id"
  end
```

My problem is how do I get the stats values out of the db and into my rails program?

In the console, I tried the following code:

```
a = Index.find(1)
a.name
a.stats
```

It correctly gets the name attribute, but I get the following error for the stats attribute

```
 undefined method `to_f' for ["0.259854651130407", "0.261425018884344"]:Array
```

The numbers shown inside the square brackets are the values of the first row of the 2D array. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm running rails 4.0.1 and here's the original migration to create the table. Is there a syntax error in here or something?

```
class CreateIndices < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :indices, {:id => false} do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.float :returns, array: true, default: []
      t.float :navs, array: true, default: []
      t.float :sharpe

      t.timestamps
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE indices ADD PRIMARY KEY (name);"
  end
end
```

EDIT 2: Here is the output from the following query in psql

query:

```
select stats from indices where id < 3
```

output:

```
stats
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {{0.259854651130407,0.261425018884344},{0.114409534648231,0.113829156756227},{2.27126744225792,2.28284789710692},{0.0562802038101342,0.0561701509132937},{4.61715902819129,4.65416265816855},{0.0
92128059492271,0.0921734852013666},{2.82058096699852,2.81919090465893},{0.0292770008925915,0.0291771074372238},{8.87572644765545,8.95993612275702}}
 {{0.259854651130407,0.261425018884344},{0.114409534648231,0.113829156756227},{2.27126744225792,2.28284789710692},{0.0562802038101342,0.0561701509132937},{4.61715902819129,4.65416265816855},{0.0
92128059492271,0.0921734852013666},{2.82058096699852,2.81919090465893},{0.0292770008925915,0.0291771074372238},{8.87572644765545,8.95993612275702}}
(2 rows)
```

Comment: What version of Rails is this?

Comment: i'm running rails 4.0.1

Comment: Check the table definition inside the database using `\d indices` from within `psql`.

Comment: In table definition it has type as double precision[], and modifiers as default '{}'::double precision[]. Also does it matter that it's declared as a 1D array when I have a 2D array, in the PG docs it seemed to imply that it doesn't since it doesn't actually enforce dimensions or lengths of arrays.

Comment: So the whole array looks more like `[[0.25, 0.26]]` than `[0.25, 0.26]`? Maybe including some of the `select stats from indices` data from `psql` would help clarify things. My current guess is that Rails4 only understands one dimensional arrays.

Comment: Ok, I've done so in the edit, as you can see the output is {{1,2},{3,4},...}

Answer (score -1):

A column of float type cannot store arrays, it can only store floats.

You could either make the column type `text` and then `serialize` the columm in your model via `serialize :stats, Array` or you can create the table via `add column :indices, :stats, :text, :array => true`.

But in your current state, you have told the database the column is a `float` type, not array so the ORM is treating the data as such when it reads/writes.

Comment: ok so just to be clear, what you're saying is rails only supports arrays of type string and not other datatypes?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that you told rails that the schema for your table was a float field, when its really an array field so that is why activerecord is trying to treat it as a float.

Comment: I see, but from your suggested solutions, it seems that I cannot declare that field to be an array of floats. I have to declare it as a text array and then convert from text to floats at some later point. Is that correct?

Comment: I believe you could declare as `:integer, :array => true`, or `:decimal, :array => true` or any field type.  Also, you can just serialize it yourself into an array of any type.  Serialized fields use text columns by default, that is why my example had it that way

Comment: ps, google is your friend here for this case as well

Comment: PostgreSQL has native support for array columns (include `double precision[]` AKA `:float` arrays), Rails3 with a gem supports them, Rails4 supports them out of the box. `serialize` is a horrible kludge that should be avoided.

Comment: Agreed, I was throwing it out as an built-in option not know which version of rails the OP is on

Comment: Ok sorry, I'm really confused now. I am running rails 4, if you look at my declaration I have "t.float, "stats", default: [], array:true" Is that not the proper way to declare the :float arrays?